# wp_list_pages bug in "number" parameter

Tags: wp-list-pages

I'm trying to build a list of the first subpage out of 10 pages.

So my page structure is this:

- Page A

  - Page A1
  - Page A2
- Page B

  - Page B1
- Page C

  - Page C1
  - Page C2
  - Page C3

And I'd like to display this list in my template:

- Page A1
- Page B1
- Page C1

I'm pretty close, but I'm stuck on a bug in WP_List_pages that causes the number parameter to not work (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10745). This means all the subpages are always displayed, whereas I only want to display the first subpage. This is the code I'm using:

```
        <?php
        $args=array(
        'post_type'     =>'page',
        'showposts'     =>10
        );
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <ul>
        <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php 
            $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$id.'&echo=0');
            $pieces = explode('"', $children);
<-- STUFF GOES HERE? -->
            ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } //if ($my_query)
        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

I'm thinking I'll need a for loop to only display the first post, but my php knowledge is lacking so I'm kind of stuck. Anybody in for a quick answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can hook into the edit_posts_per_page filter that fires in WP_List_pages right before the pagination is determined.

```
add_action( 'edit_posts_per_page, 'limit_list_pages' );

function limit_list_pages() {
        $post_type ='post';
        $edit_per_page='edit_' . $post_type . '_per_page';
        $per_page=(int)get_user_option( $edit_per_page );
        if ( empty( $per_page ) || $per_page < 1 )
            $per_page=10; //<--- Change this to your new per page number

        return $per_page;
    }
```